# VS2015 mpirxx error C4146

Tags: c++, mpir

I am using Visual studio community 2015 and I want to set up a projects with mpirxx.

Recently I' have compiled the mpirxx code to get the debug library file. In my project I have included the mpirxx.h file and linked mpirxx.lib, but when I try to compile I get 17 identical errors from mpirxx.h from multiple lines around the code.

```
Error C4146 : The unary operator 'minus' was applied to unsigned. The result remains unsigned.
```

Here's an example :

```
212 - __mpz_set_ui_safe(p, -static_cast&lt;mpir_ui&gt;(l));
```

Is this a know problem of the library? Should I change it? 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is a known misfeature in visual studio. It can be disabled (don't treat warnings as errors, don't enable some "security" features (SDL)).

Comment: Looking at the context of each static_cast, `l` is always negative.  So I think this is correct.  Just disable 'treat warnings as errors' and ignore the warnings.

Comment: Disabling SDL worked! Thanks for your time.